# Using Child methods from a List<Parent> objects

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Currently I've got a ton of methods that are all similar: From a list of `Parent`s, I'm casting an object to it's proper type and then `Draw`ing it. This works fine, but is extremely unwieldy as each method is exactly identical other than the cast.

It looks something like this

```
public class Parent
{ 
    public virtual void Draw()
    {
        //deliberately nothing
    }
}

public class Child1 : Parent
{ 
    public override void Draw()
    {
        //draw this object, but slightly different method than Parent
    }
}

public class Child2 : Parent
{ 
    public override void Draw()
    {
        //draw this, but slightly different method than Child1 and Parent
    }
}

/////////////////////////

List<Parent> parent_list = new List<Parent>();
parent_list.Add(new Child1());
parent_list.Add(new Child2());

/////////////////////////

foreach (Parent parent in parent_list)
{
    parent.Draw(); //Would like to use child1 and child2's draw
}

/////////////////////////

///instead I'm doing a manual cast for each child class
foreach (Parent parent in parent_list)
{
    Child1 child = (Child1)parent;
    child.Draw();
}

foreach (Parent parent in parent_list)
{
    Child2 child = (Child2)parent;
    child.Draw();
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that it's trying to call `Parent.Draw()` when I want to it to call `Child.Draw()` I'm positive there's a better way to design the code, but I can't figure it out.

**How can I call elegantly call `Draw` on all the elements of in list when the only thing in common is their parent?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your child classes are inherited from Parent (otherwise it wouldn't be possible to add child object's to parents collection and have `Draw` method overridden). Also I don't understand why you are calling to `this.Draw` inside `Draw` methods? It will cause recursive calls. You should have method implementations there

```
public class Parent 
{ 
    public virtual void Draw()
    {
       // parent implementation of Draw
    }
}

public class Child1 : Parent
{ 
    public override void Draw()
    {
        // child1 implementation of Draw
    }
}

public class Child2 : Parent
{ 
    public override void Draw()
    {
        // use base.Draw() to call parent implementation
        // child2 implementation of Draw
    }
}
```

Then when you do

```
foreach (Parent parent in parent_list)
{
    parent.Draw(); 
}
```

Overridden (child) methods will be called here due to polymorphism.

Comment: Further, if the Child `Draw` calls want to take advantage of the `Parent` versions, they can call `base.Draw()`, not `this.Draw()`.

Comment: I've updated the code example to more accurately reflect what I meant. In any case, it was a matter of one the parents methods being virtual instead of override (or something. You'd think I'd know considering I just fixed it) and so I've solved my problem. I'll accept this answer since it was the solution to the original question. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Lazrberezosky's answer was correct for the general case, so I've marked his a correct.

But for my personal issue, it was that one of the many Parent classes I was using was marked as `virtual` instead of `override` so it incorrectly looking above the `Parent` class into its parent, which may have well been `Object` and giving me an error.

```
 Object.Draw    
 Parent.Draw - Virtual    
  Child.Draw - Override //incorrectly was virtual in my code    
G_Child.Draw - Override
```

When I called `Parent.Draw` on the list, it went to `Parent.Draw` and saw that `Child.Draw` was `virtual` so then, I think, it went back up to `Object.Draw` and threw a compiler error.

*Feel free to edit for clarity.*