# Using child type in generic function from a List<Parent> object

Tags: c#, generics

My problem is similar to [Using Child methods from a List<Parent> objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105566/using-child-methods-from-a-listparent-objects) except rather than call a method I want to use the child type in a generic method. For example:

```
class Parent { }
class Child1 : Parent { }
class Child2 : Parent { }
// could be other child classes, unknown to the Process class

class Process
{
    public Process()
    {
        List<Parent> L = new List<Parent>();
        Child1 C1 = new Child1();
        Child2 C2 = new Child2();
        L.Add(C1);
        L.Add(C2);

        foreach(Parent P in L)
        {
            DoSomething(P);
        }
    }

    public void DoSomething<TypeP>(TypeP P)
    {
        // P is 'Child1', 'Child2' or potentially something else
        // TypeP is 'Parent'

        //TypeP = P.GetType(); //doesnt work
        //DoSomethingElse<P.GetType()>(); //doesnt work
        DoSomethingElse<TypeP>();
    }

    public void DoSomethingElse<T>()
    {
        // T is 'Parent'
        T R = Activator.CreateInstance<T>(); // want R to be 'Child1' or 'Child2'
    }
}
```

I'd like *DoSomethingElse* to be called with the type of *C1* or *C2* rather than the the 'Parent' type. I've been round a few times but cant find a way to get this to work. I feel like it should be trivial given *P* in *DoSomething* is the correct type.

EDIT:
The reason DoSomethingElse is generic is because there could be any number of child classes derived from the parent. I used Child1 and Child2 as an example, but in reality there could be quite a few more and so a switch statement in DoSomethingElse isn't feasible because the number of derived classes is unknown.

Comment: use dynamics or cast as and check if not null?

Comment: I feel someone ought to point out that this feels a bit wrong, if it matters so much what the type parameter to `DoSomethingElse` is, maybe these three types shouldn't actually be arranged the way they are?

Comment: See this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2011/04/05/visitor-and-multiple-dispatch-via-c-dynamic/

Comment: The reason these don't work is because Generics are a compile time thing - the compiler decides how the generic method should be called. This is why trying to set the type of TypeP at runtime as you have will never work. Since you only know what the type is at run time your options (assuming you need the list `L` to stay as `List<Parent>` are all pretty much around doing type checks at runtime...

Comment: @Leszek Repie replacing "DoSomething(P);" with "DoSomething(P as dynamic);" seems to work, although I have no idea why at this stage

Comment: I had forgotten about dynamic. Dynamic basically does method binding at runtime instead of compile time which is why it works. It is also worse performance (since it is doing things that would normally have been already done by the compiler) and can be a code smell too.

Comment: Call me confused. Using dynamic works in the provided example; It compiles and behaves as expected. However my actual code which has the same syntax gives an error "Cannot pass argument with dynamic type to generic local function '<Function Name>' with inferred type arguments"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of things wrong with the code above.
Generics only work for types known at compile time. We upcast all our values to base class here:

```
// L is a List<Parent>
L.Add(C1);
L.Add(C2);
```

So if we use generics in `DoSomething<TypeP>` compiler will always use `Parent` for `TypeP`.
We'd need to work with type known only on *run time*, our options are limited. Something that is called DLR is used for dealing with run-time values. 
The type that DLR works with is called `dynamic`.

So let's change the `foreach` iteration variable to `dynamic`:

```
foreach (dynamic P in L)
{
    DoSomething(P);
}
```

Now we can use generics with constraint that `TChild` should be derived from `Parent`:

```
public void DoSomething<TChild>(TChild P) where TChild : Parent
{    
    ...
    DoSomethingElse(P);
}
```

We cannot use this method signature as it will require us to specify the type on method invocation:

```
public void DoSomethingElse<TChild>()
```

To let compiler infer type we can pass instance of `TChild` that compiler can use to infer type.:

```
public void DoSomethingElse<TChild>(TChild P) where TChild : Parent
{
    // TChild is Child now
    var R = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TChild)); // want R to be 'Child1' or 'Child2'
}
```

Here is **[DotNetFiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)**

Comment: The number of child classes is unknown (hence generics). I've made an edit which hopefully makes it clearer.

Comment: @xareth Updated my answer

Comment: `The number of child classes is unknown (hence generics)` - this does not really makes sense to me, what is the connection between 'the number is unknown' and 'hence generics' ?

Comment: @Maarten Perhaps my logic is incorrect but the method is generic so it can handle any type of 'parent : child' class (just typing that makes me think its incorrect). The real reason for using a generic type is to eventually pass it to Activator.CreateInstance()

Comment: Marked this as the solution since it works and compiles for the given problem. Similar to the comment by Leszek Repie. Problem is it didn't actually translate to a solution in my code. I get "Cannot pass argument with dynamic type to generic local function '<Function Name>' with inferred type arguments". I suspect this might be because my Parent class is actually a "Parent : AnotherClass<AnInterface>" class.

Comment: Thanks Fabjan. I worked it out. Turns out I needed an additional generic type to be specified. So 'DoSomethingElse<TChild>()' became 'DoSomethingElse<TChild, AnotherType>()'. Once I changed that your answer finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options here:

1. Replace DoSomethingElse with a virtual method at Parent class, so any child has to overwrite the behavior you need. Then it's usual thing to just call that overridden method via parent-typed instance (Liskov substitution principle). Preferred way, IMHO.

   ```
   public void DoSomething<TypeP>(TypeP P)
   {
       P.DoSomethingElse(); // this is virtual method to be overwritten by children types
   }
   ```
2. "Generics specialization" approach (that seems a bit hacky for me as C# naturally lacks of some C++ features, but... you may find it suitable) https://stackoverflow.com/a/3337928/1964969

Answer (score 0):

You could check for type using is keyword:

```
public void DoSomething<TypeP>(TypeP P)
        {
            if (P is Child1)
            {

            }
            else if(P is Child2)
            {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case you want to call `Activator.CreatInstance<T>()` but there is an alternative. There is a method `[Activator.CreatInstance(Type type)][1]`.

You can use this by changing your dosomething method slightly

```
public void DoSomethingElse(Parent p)
{
    var R = Activator.CreateInstance(p.GetType());
}
```

Of course without knowing what you then are doing with it I don't know if this necessarily helps. You may still need some kind of switch statement on the type of R to then make use of this new object. If however you can from this point on just treat `R` as being of type `Parent` then this should help you out.